Can we get Parent Handle (Struct device *dev ) from Child node Device Driver?
I have a device tree like below :
&bus {

    child_1 : childNode@50 {
        cell-index = <0>;
        ..........
        status "ok";
    };

    child_2 : childNode@70 {
        cell-index = <1>;
        ..........
        status "ok";
    };
};

In my child driver i'll be needing Parent's handle before child driver is binded to its Parent that is "bus".
Why i need Parent handle ?
I have a requirement that when "child_1" or "child_2" driver is starting to probe i need to keep the parent or master driver "bus" in High power State by calling power management API's and for that reason, i need Parent's Device handle. So, that i can call below Kernel API's
pm_runtime_getsync(struct device *bus_handle); /*Here "bus_handle" is handle to "bus"(parent) device*/
..........Once the child device probe is completed.....will call below to make parent to suspend....
pm_runtime_putsync(struct device *bus_handle);

For this am checking if there is any device tree calls exisit to fetch the Parent's struct device* handle
I do see this : struct device_node *parent_node = of_get_parent(child_node);
And again i need to convert this parent_node type to struct device. Before that i need to check if there is any cleaner way to do that ?

No, you don’t need it. It’s done automatically via device links. Either your parent, or your children , or both drivers are broken, if you still think it won’t work.

Your driver cannot do anything much with the device until its probe function is called. E.g. a platform device driver will get called with a pointer to a struct platform_device, which contains a struct device dev member for the child device, and that struct device will contain a struct device *parent member pointing to the child's parent's struct device, if it has one.
